# Nodejs install is not working, [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/include/node/'

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, socket.io, npm

I'm trying to install Node, socket.io and npm using the following:

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get install libv8-2.0.3 libv8-dev libv8-dbg libssl-dev curl
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.3.tar.gz
tar zxvf node-v0.4.3.tar.gz
cd node-v0.4.3
sudo ./configure && make && make install
sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
sudo npm install socket.io
```

However the script fails on:

```
sudo ./configure && make && make install
```

It is unable to create the node directory in usr/local/include. I'm using sudo and it's not working... I've got a feeling that it's got something to do with my Ubuntu 11.04 install being installed from Windows... but I could be wrong. When I go to usr/local/include i've not got permissions to do anything even though i've got root access....

Do you know why this isn't working?

Here is the full error message:

```
Cannot create folder '/usr/local/include/node/' (original error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/include/node/')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sudo bash
```

then stuff without sudo

```
exit
```

Comment: I actually have an alias to sudo as judo just so I can do **judo bash**

Comment: also, sudo bash is a bit naughty.

Comment: Can't you do `su` simply on Ubuntu? ... Install Debian, no sudo problems ;)

Comment: You can if you set a password for root. I don't have one set but it's really just a personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had permission denied error in executing `./configure` command so I followed this:

1. Right click on file `configure` and `/root/node/tools/waf-light`
   in *Permissions* tab.
2. Check the option

   ```
   Allow executing file as program
   ```

   This will give permission to both these file to execute.
3. Now execute `./configure` command.